# HP KVM Server Console Switch G2 error

Tags: hp, console, keyboard-video-mouse

I have a HP KVM Server Console Switch G2 that I am having a problem with.  When I try to open up a KVM session with a server I am getting the message, "Error:  All video channels in use", and the session will fail to launch.  Rebooting the server console switch will then allow sessions to launch after this but inevitably it will return to this state after sitting for a couple of days with no activity... Not to mention it then takes some extra time to get onto the server.  Does anyone know how to avoid this error or fix it?  The manual didn't have this specific error under troubleshooting and some HP support forums have yet to yield a response.